# Is there a large performance hit when creating a class vs sticking with the singletonian nature of required modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, singleton

I'm architecting the model layer on an MVC structured project. I'm looking at 2 solutions - listed below - and the performance hit from instantiating a new class every request.

(if anyone else has another pattern recommendation, I'm open to it)

**Singleton**

```
const MySQLConnection = require("../configs/mysql");

// Get a session
module.exports.getSession = async (sessionToken) => {    
    // Check the DB
    const queryString = "SELECT * FROM `session` WHERE `session_token` = ?";
    const queryData = [sessionToken];
    return MySQLConnection.query(queryString, queryData);
};

// Create a session
module.exports.createSession = async (userID, sessionToken, ipAddress, browserName, browserVersion, platform) => {      
    // Check the DB
    const queryString = "INSERT INTO `session`  (user_id,session_token, ip_address, browser_name, browser_version, platform) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    const queryData = [userId, sessionToken, ipAddress, browserName, browserVersion, platform];
    return MySQLConnection.query(queryString, queryData);

};

// Expire a session
module.exports.expireSession = async (sessionToken) => {
    ...
};
```

**Class based**

```
const MySQLConnection = require("../configs/mysql");

module.exports = class Session {

    constructor(options) {
        this.userId = options.userId || defaults.userId;
        this.sessiontoken = sessiontoken.name || sessiontoken.name;
   }

    // Get session
    getSession() {              
        // Check the DB
        const queryString = "SELECT * FROM `session` WHERE `session_token` = ?";
        const queryData = [sessionToken];
        return MySQLConnection.query(queryString, queryData);
    }

    // Create session
    createSession() {
        // Check the DB
        const queryString = "INSERT INTO `session`  (user_id,session_token, ip_address, browser_name, browser_version, platform) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        const queryData = [userId, sessionToken, ipAddress, browserName, browserVersion, platform];
        return MySQLConnection.query(queryString, queryData);
    }
};
```

**The singleton would be called like this:**

```
const SessionModel = require("../models/session");
const sessionResult = SessionModel.getSession("sj8f9dsafyh9sfafs");
```

**The class would be called like this:**

```
const SessionModel = require("../models/session");
const session = new SessionModel({sessionToken: "sj8f9dsafyh9sfafs"})
const sessionResult = session.getSession();
```

The singleton doesn't create a new object every request, whereas the class does. I would like the ability to store model related data somewhere (and not affect other users making a request at the same time). Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My take:  I really doubt you'll see a meaningful performance hit.

The difference depends more on what the module does.  If you need a factory that allows you to create independent instances, take the class-based approach (you could always do this with functions before we got all fancy-pants with classes).

If you don't, I wouldn't over complicate things and just construct your module.exports one member at a time.

Comment: I ran I load tester against the code. Check my answer, if you're interested.

Comment: I'm not surprised by the result.  My main point you don't load modules that often, and 10% extra on a tiny amount of stuff isn't worth optimizing for.  Other factors would be better to dictate the architecture.

Answer (score 0):

I ran a load tester (artillery) against the configurations. The first comparison is a best case scenario (low line count), the second is a worst case scenario(high line count).

Classes run about 10% slower than singletons.

**Best case:**

*Singleton*

```
Summary report @ 13:34:36(-0600) 2018-01-02
  Scenarios launched:  600
  Scenarios completed: 600
  Requests completed:  600
  RPS sent: 19.71
  Request latency:
    min: 4.9
    max: 22
    median: 5.9
    p95: 8.2
    p99: 9.8
  Scenario duration:
    min: 5.7
    max: 52
    median: 7
    p95: 9.4
    p99: 11.4
  Scenario counts:
    0: 600 (100%)
  Codes:
    200: 600
```

*Class*

```
Summary report @ 13:38:08(-0600) 2018-01-02
  Scenarios launched:  600
  Scenarios completed: 600
  Requests completed:  600
  RPS sent: 19.7
  Request latency:
    min: 4.9
    max: 18.3
    median: 6.1
    p95: 8.3
    p99: 10
  Scenario duration:
    min: 5.6
    max: 37.1
    median: 7.2
    p95: 9.7
    p99: 12.2
  Scenario counts:
    0: 600 (100%)
  Codes:
    200: 600
```

**Worst Case**

*Singleton*

```
Summary report @ 13:51:35(-0600) 2018-01-02
  Scenarios launched:  600
  Scenarios completed: 600
  Requests completed:  600
  RPS sent: 19.71
  Request latency:
    min: 5
    max: 19.3
    median: 6.9
    p95: 9.1
    p99: 10.6
  Scenario duration:
    min: 5.9
    max: 44.5
    median: 8.1
    p95: 10.5
    p99: 12.5
  Scenario counts:
    0: 600 (100%)
  Codes:
    200: 600
```

*Class*

```
Summary report @ 13:41:18(-0600) 2018-01-02
  Scenarios launched:  600
  Scenarios completed: 600
  Requests completed:  600
  RPS sent: 19.71
  Request latency:
    min: 4.9
    max: 42.9
    median: 7.2
    p95: 9.6
    p99: 12.1
  Scenario duration:
    min: 5.7
    max: 69
    median: 8.4
    p95: 11.2
    p99: 14.2
  Scenario counts:
    0: 600 (100%)
  Codes:
    200: 600
```